# How to work with Health Endpoint Monitoring Pattern using Azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, health-monitoring

Am working on Health Endpoint Monitoring Pattern which is used for monitoring and health check of resources like "**Storage, SQL Database** etc" in Azure. For this, I followed [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/health-endpoint-monitoring#monitoring-endpoints-in-azure-hosted-applications) and known that "There were three ways to monitor endpoints in Azure" like:
[image]

From these, I went with **custom utility** with the coding in project and checking the health status in local which is working finely. Now, am trying to do same thing with the Azure Portal. But, I didn't find anyway to "**How to monitor Health Status of my applications through Portal**". Please suggest me, If there any way to do Health Check for Applications through portal

Comment: Have you tried use the application insights? It can monitor the sql depency, cpu etc.

Comment: @Ivan Yang thank you for reply, with the help of Application Insights I can get only one resource results like SQL dependency and its cpu. But, am trying to get all resources Health Status results at one place like a dashboard.